# Related List on Account screen no longer "crunching down"

Tags: related-list, setup

This might be ridiculously easy to answer but I am having a wood for the trees moment.

My related lists on the Account screen no longer have the more/fewer buttons, the go to list button - they are displaying expanded as a default with no way of minimising.

How on earth have I done this? I cannot remember for the life of me and leafing through the setup menus is proving fruitless.

Comment: Have you tried on another browser/computer? How many related records are showing? I think by default they will show only if you have more than 5 related records.

Comment: No, another user was mentioning this to me too. Affecting Chrome and Firefox from what I see, and I *think* it is only the Account object. Affecting lists which can have 20-30 contacts in them etc.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of any detail screen is a set of links that reads "Always show me fewer/more records per related list." You can set this up to a maximum of 100 per related list. If there are fewer than the number of default records shown, you will see all items instead of the "show more"/"go to list" links. You can also select any record you can view, and add the parameter "?rowsperlist=5" to reset it back to five items per list (e.g. https://na1.salesforce.com/0011000000ABCDE?rowsperlist=5). It must be a record you can view that is not overridden by a visualforce page.